# List of methods that are invoked by reflection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

I am working on J2EE application and we often have problem that we are not sure if some method is invoked by reflection during runtime or not.

Do you have any idea how can I find out all such places?

Comment: @Pshemo - please describe your idea in more detail?

Comment: @Paweł out of curiosity, what do you need this information for?

Comment: How would you possibly be able to tell that? Suppose you have a code path which allows a method to be called based on user input... that means *anything* (that you have access to) can be invoked via reflection.

Comment: If you are looking for the invocation of methods on specific objects, can you use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`?

Comment: @AdamSiemion - I work with big application and some time you find method that seems to be unused (no references in code), but you always have to check if it is not invoked by reflection. So it would be useful to have such list, so you don't have check each time.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I need list of methods that are indeed invoked by reflection, not all those that might be.

Comment: Invoked by reflection for one specific run then? Or over some time period? It's really unclear...

Comment: @JonSkeet - over all time when application was running. In case of our application it is about one month.

Comment: And do you have any central place which *uses* the reflection API? If so, add logging there. If not, centralize it as a first step...

Answer (score 0):

Normally in such a case if the tests are properly done and thorough enough, you could try to remove the suspected unused code piece and then run the full test suite, if all is fine then good, otherwise you can narrow it down based on the failed test.

Real world is more than often not this perfect though.

My best bet would be to use a text content based search (e.g. Notepad++ **"Search in Files"** as one option) through all of your codebase (one which also traverses JARs and compiled classes) and search for the method name, since if someone is invoking it, it should hopefully at least do it via the method name.

(Note that this is **not** a one-size-fits-all solution since different things can be invoked in different obfuscated ways, e.g. methods will not always get invoked by their full name.)

For example things like this could occur in the codebase:

```
for (Method m : allMethods) {
    String mname = m.getName();
    if (mname.startsWith("mySpecialPartialHandle")){
        // Invoke mySpecialPartialHandleMethodWithTrailingWords()
    }
}
```

It's worth a shot though.

The more common the name the more you'll have to dig through the returned results though.